# Where is the source code for Ruby's operators?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for evidence of the unary `&`'s to_proc behaviour in Ruby source code so that I can write about it. Where are the implementations for the native behaviours of these ruby operators kept? I looked in parse.y and have no idea how to search for this as there are thousands of matches for "&". What's the best way to go about finding ruby implementation details for this? Is there documentation for the ruby source code itself?

Comment: The Ruby source file `proc.c` has a function `rb_sym_to_proc(VALUE sym)`. That doesn't show how `&` gets parsed, but it's a start...

Comment: If you are unable to find where `to_proc` behaviour is implemented in the ruby code, you definitely should not write about it.

Comment: Which implementation of Ruby are you talking about? There are about 8 that are in production use and another 20 or so in various stages of development and/or abandonment.

Comment: In the ISO Ruby Language Specification, the relevant part is in Section 11.3.2 *Method Arguments*, Subsection *Semantics*, Clause e) 6).

Comment: @JörgWMittag It should be assumed that I'm talking about MRI Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby language itself is documented on ruby-lang.org. In particular, there are pages for Ruby's [grammar](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/lib/racc/rdoc/grammar_en_rdoc.html), [syntax](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax_rdoc.html), and [method calling semantics](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html). For the block-ifying behavior of the `&` operator, you might find ["Proc to Block Conversion"](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Proc+to+Block+Conversion) useful.

I'm not sure where the block-ifying behavior of `&` is implemented, but it's relatively straightforward:

1. If the argument to `&` is a `Proc`, then blockify it
2. Otherwise, call `to_proc` on it and blockify *that* result (failing if `to_proc` isn't defined or fails)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering where in the ruby repository I could find the implementation. I'm curious if there is any documentation for navigating the https://github.com/ruby/ruby/ source code better.